# IEnumerable.Take(0) on File.ReadLines seems not to dispose/close the File handle

Tags: c#

I have a function which Skips `n` lines of code and Takes `y` lines from a given file using `File.ReadLines` with `Skip` and `Take` combination. When I try to open the file given by `filePath` the next time:

```
string[] Lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(0).Take(0).ToArray();
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
    // ...
}
```

I get a `File in use by another process` exception on the "`using`" line.

It looks like `IEnumerable.Take(0)` is the culprit, since it returns an empty `IEnumerable` without enumerating on the object returned by `File.ReadLines()`, which I believe is not disposing the file.

Am I right? Should they not enumerate to avoid this kind of errors? How to do this properly?

Comment: You *definitely* have the `ToArray` call? I'd expect that to dispose of the iterator, which should work its way up appropriately. Could you provide a [mcve]? (I would expect you to be able to show this all in a `Main` method.)

Comment: Yes, right, it is called. Remember it is called NOT on the File.ReadLines IEnumerable, but on the Take(0) returned IEnumerable

Comment: Yes, but I'd expect that to end up disposing of the original iterator. (It would be fairly easy to prove that using your own iterator method.)

Comment: @CodeCaster: What, exactly? A problem with `File.ReadLines`, or a more general problem with `Take(0)`?

Comment: Its actually fairly easy to reproduce it. Just copy paste the the ReadLines and using (StreamWriter...) line in console application, with 0 as argument to Take, you can reproduce it

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't inherit from IDisposable because typically, the class that implements it only gives you the *promise* of being enumerable, it hasn't actually done anything yet that warrants disposal. However, when you enumerate over it, you first retrieve an `IEnumerator` by calling the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` method, and typically, the underlying object you get back *does* implement `IDisposable`. For `File.ReadLines`, the file isn't opened until you start enumerating over it, so the object you get from `File.ReadLines` doesn't need disposing, but the enumerator you get, does.

Comment: Looking at the source, it appears Take(0) does not dispose of its source iterator: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ceb7d3d4f0a39720,references

Comment: @Dennis_E: Actually, that looks okay - because the `foreach` loop does the right thing. I think it's actually `File.ReadLines` which is broken here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry, but it says `if (count > 0)`. If count equals 0, the foreach loop is never run. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Dennis_E: Yes - you're missing the fact that there's nothing to dispose of until `foreach` calls `GetEnumerator`. An `IEnumerable<T>` shouldn't need to be disposed of, whereas an `IEnumerator<T>` *does* need to be disposed. If you don't call `GetEnumerator()`, it should be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course, that makes sense. dur

Answer (score 40):

This is basically a bug in `File.ReadLines`, not `Take`. `ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, which should logically be lazy, but it *eagerly* opens the file. Unless you actually iterate over the return value, you have nothing to dispose.

It's *also* broken in terms of only iterating once. For example, you should be able to write:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("text.txt");
var query = from line1 in lines
            from line2 in lines
            select line1 + line2;
```

... that should give a cross-product of lines in the file. It doesn't, due to the brokenness.

`File.ReadLines` *should* be implemented something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string filename)
{
    return ReadLines(() => File.OpenText(filename));
}

private static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(Func<TextReader> readerProvider)
{
    using (var reader = readerProvider())
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it's not :(

Options:

- Use the above instead of `File.ReadLines`
- Write your own implementation of `Take` which *always* starts iterating, e.g.

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
  {
      // TODO: Argument validation
      using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
      {
          while (count > 0 && iterator.MoveNext())
          {
              count--;
              yield return iterator.Current;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: "`File.ReadLines` _should_ be implemented something like this" Like a boss.

Comment: Nothing better than having Jon Skeet show up and tell you that the BCL implementation is crazy and your code is not.

Answer (score 19):

From the comment above [`File.ReadLines()` in the Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/ReadLinesIterator.cs,12), it becomes obvious that the team responsible *knew* about this "bug":

> Known issues which cannot be changed to remain compatible with 4.0:
>
> - The underlying `StreamReader` is allocated upfront for the `IEnumerable<T>` before 
>     `GetEnumerator` has even been called. While this is good in that exceptions such as 
>     `DirectoryNotFoundException` and `FileNotFoundException` are thrown directly by 
>     `File.ReadLines` (which the user probably expects), it also means that the **reader 
>     will be leaked if the user never actually foreach's over the enumerable (and hence 
>     calls Dispose on at least one `IEnumerator<T>` instance)**.

So they wanted `File.ReadLines()` to throw immediately when passed an invalid or unreadable path, as opposed to throwing when enumerating.

The alternative is simple: not calling `Take(0)`, or instead not reading the file altogether if you aren't actually interested in its contents.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the root cause is `Enumerable.Take` iterator doesn't dispose an underlying iterator if the `count` is zero, since the code doesn't enter the `foreach` loop - see [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ceb7d3d4f0a39720).
If one modifies the code in following way the issue gets resolved:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count)
{
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (--count < 0) break;
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Claiming `Take` is at fault for not disposing an object it avoided creating in the first place doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Indeed. Nothing should *have* to call GetEnumerator and dispose the result.